# CUnit: fail with dynamically generated string

Tags: c, unit-testing, cunit

## Background

CUnit provides the `CU_FAIL` function, which allows one to indicate the failure of a test with a chosen message. Calling `CU_FAIL("failure message")` would fail the enclosing test, printing a string which includes `CU_FAIL("failure message")`.

## Problem

I would like to indicate offending parameters in my failure message. If I dynamically set a variable `char * message` to a desired message such as `"Expected i = 5, but i = 6."` and then call `CU_FAIL(message)`, then the test fails, but only the string `CU_FAIL(message)` is printed. The contents of `message` are not printed.

## Question

How can I have CUnit fail a test while printing the contents of a dynamically generated string? I am using version 2.1-3.

Answer (score 0):

Currently is not possible. The project moved to gitlab and the there is related [issue](https://gitlab.com/cunity/cunit/issues/26).